# Storing logic inside database

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, logic

This is NOT about stored procedures (or at least i don't think it is).

Lets say i have a database. A database has some cities in it and events that take place in those cities. Some people are going to use this site and they want to get notified about certain events, when they enter the site. 
The rules for specifying what events they want to be notified about are supposed to be general.

For example, i would want user to be able to say "I want to be notified about all events, that will take place on sunday, in city that was founded between year 1200 and 1400, in the country which name starts with the letter "F" or which is in South America", which would be translate in pseudo-logic-code of:

```
  (
  event.date.day == Sunday 
  and 
  event.city.founded_date.year.between(1200, 1400)
  ) 
AND 
  (
  event.city.country.starts_with("F")
  or
  event.city.country.continent == "South Africa"
  )
```

The rules like "continent is", "day is", "foundation date is between" et cetera are to be predefined, user will choose it, but i want to be able to add new rules in future.

What is the best way to store such logic? The only solution i can come up with is a "NotificationGatherer" model. It would contain id of a user, and a string with json.
I would create a json binary tree, for this particular case, the capitalized "AND" would be a root with two children - the inner and and inner or.
The first children would have two simple conditions, which would reflect the actual conditions as abive.

Then i would have a method that's called on user's request, which would either:

1. Evaluate the value (true/false) of this conditions set for all upcoming events

   or
2. Form a queryset with filters, which would fetch all the upcoming events that satisfy given conditions (much more difficult and much more efficient).

Now, is this even a good approach, or should i try something else?
It seems rather complex (I already see how painful it would be to test it), and i can imagine that a lot of people could have needed something like this in the past, yet i can't find any suggestions, because any searching for "logic in database" automatically points me to articles/questions about stored procedures.

If that makes any difference, I'm using django and mysql.

Comment: That is the task of an Async Queue with a schedule. Check Celery

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll read about Celery later, especially because i'll need some scheduling in my application anyway, but at the first glance: it was not the point of my question. Notifications were just an example of what i would need such logic-storing for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was for me, I would store the rules in database, then
process them from time to time using Celery.

For the model part, I think multi-table inheritance is the way to go, since different rules need to store different data.
In my opinion, [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) is your friend here:

I suggest something such as:

```
from django.db import models
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel


class AbtractRuleObject(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        """Will handle actual filtering of the event queryset"""
        raise NotImplementedError

    def match_instance(self, instance):
        raise NotImplementedError

class RuleSet(AbtractRuleObject):
    """Will manage the painful part o handling the OR / AND logic inside the database"""
    NATURE_CHOICES = (
        ('or', 'OR'),
        ('and', 'AND'),
    )
    nature = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=NATURE_CHOICES, default='and')

    # since a set can belong to another set, etc.
    parent_set = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        """This is rather naive and could be optimized"""
        if not self.parent_set:
            # this is a root rule set so we just filter according to registered rules
            for rule in self.rules:
                if self.nature == 'and':
                    queryset = rule.filter_queryset(queryset)
                elif self.nature == 'or':
                    queryset = queryset | rule.filter_queryset(queryset)
        else:
            # it has children rules set
            for rule_set in self.children:
                if self.nature == 'and':
                    queryset = rule_set.filter_queryset(queryset)
                elif self.nature == 'or':
                    queryset = queryset | rule_set.filter_queryset(queryset)
        return queryset

    def match_instance(self, instance):
        if not self.parent_set:
            if self.nature == 'and':
                return all([rule_set.match_instance(instance) for rule_set in self.children])
            if self.nature == 'any':
                return any([rule_set.match_instance(instance) for rule_set in self.children])
        else:
            if self.nature == 'and':
                return all([rule_set.match_instance(instance) for rule_set in self.children])
            if self.nature == 'any':
                return any([rule_set.match_instance(instance) for rule_set in self.children])

class Rule(AbtractRuleObject, PolymorphicModel):
    """Base class for all rules"""
    attribute = models.CharField(help_text="Attribute of the model on which the rule will apply")
    rule_set = models.ForeignKey(RuleSet, related_name='rules')

class DateRangeRule(Rule):
    start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        filters = {}
        if self.start:
            filters['{0}__gte'.format(self.attribute)] = self.start
        if self.end:
            filters['{0}__lte'.format(self.attribute)] = self.end
        return queryset.filter(**filters)

    def match_instance(self, instance):
        start_ok = True
        end_ok = True
        if self.start:
            start_ok = getattr(instance, self.attribute) >= self.start
        if self.end:
            end_ok = getattr(instance, self.attribute) <= self.end

        return start_ok and end_ok

class MatchStringRule(Rule):
    match = models.CharField()
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        filters = {'{0}'.format(self.attribute): self.match}
        return queryset.filter(**filters)

    def match_instance(self, instance):
        return getattr(instance, self.attribute) == self.match

class StartsWithRule(Rule):
    start = models.CharField()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        filters = {'{0}__startswith'.format(self.attribute): self.start}
        return queryset.filter(**filters)

    def match_instance(self, instance):
        return getattr(instance, self.attribute).startswith(self.start)
```

Now, assuming your `Event` and `City` models look like:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    founded_date = models.DateField()

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
```

Then you can use my example as follow:

```
global_set = RuleSet(nature='and')
global_set.save()

set1 = RuleSet(nature='and', parent_set=global_set)
set1.save()

year_range = DateRangeRule(start=datetime.date(1200, 1, 1),
                           end=datetime.date(1400, 1, 1),
                           attribute='city__founded_date',
                           rule_set=set1)
year_range.save()

set2 = RuleSet(nature='or', parent_set=global_set)
set2.save()

startswith_f = StartsWithRule(start='F',
                              attribute='city__country__name')
                              rule_set=set2)
startswith_f.save()

exact_match = MatchStringRule(match='South Africa',
                              attribute='city__country__continent')
                              rule_set=set2)
exact_match.save()

queryset = Event.objects.all()

# Magic happens here

# Get all instances corresponding to the rules
filtered_queryset = global_set.filter_queryset(queryset)

# Check if a specific instance match the rules
assert global_set.match_instance(filtered_queryset[0]) == True
```

The code is absolutely untested, but I think it could eventually work or, at least, give you
an implementation idea.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I once had to write a ttw SQL query builder (a specialized one hopefully - only a small set of related tables with known schemas) and my solutions was close to this one.

Comment: Thanks ! I thinks the hard part here would probably be the front-end ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, awesome response, at first glance it looks like exactly like what i would need, will mark as best answer if nothing better pops up. As for the front-end - with my example i tried to simplify  what i need, no real notifications involved in the actual application and it will be me who actually puts those rules, so i can as well just write some scripts and ignore front-end ;). I just wanted it to be as flexible as possible from the beginning, without needing to rewrite everything everytime i will need another type of rule

Comment: Wow, i've just realized that for the purpose of this example i've made up an entire new continent.

Comment: @piezol I totally understand your use case and, in fact, I'll probably face a similar one soon, so I may create a reusable package from this example. I'll share it here if I do :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not about logic in database, it's better called storing filter patterns or storing filter preferences.

In general, you want give your users ability to create and store in profile settings filters that will extract from database all events matching them and send to user notification about them.

First, you should consider how much deep that filters have to be. It can be for example like this:

1. model `FilterSet` - will have some global settings (for example notification type) and will be assigned to particular user
2. model `Filter` - will have one rule of filtering (or set of rules that comes together, for example date range) and will be assigned to `FilterSet`

Each user should be able to define more than one filterset. All filters, when query is created, will be joined together with AND (except of some rules inside filter. Type of that particular filter will set it).

After creating some types of filters (range of dates when even starts, days of week etc) you will store filter type in one column and filter parameters in other columns or in one column using json serialization.

When notifications should be sent, processor will check each `FilterSet` if it is returning some data, if yes, it will send returned data to owner of that `FilterSet`.

It's not that complex as storing whole WHERE conditions inside json, but it will give similar flexibility. You just have to create more than one `FilterSet` for user to cover some complex case.